# Get type of AutomationEvent C# UIAutomation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I was wondering how I could get a specific type of action on `AutomationElement`? I have all the details when it comes to AutomationElement using

```
AutomationFocusChangedEventHandler handler = new AutomationFocusChangedEventHandler(OnFocusChange);
Automation.AddAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler(handler);
```

And there I can get all the information about focused element.

But I need to know if for example button was clicked, if edit input was edited or window was closed and so on.

I know that kind of information is provided in AccEvent and it distinguish events between Property, Focus and Automation with further details each.

*Basically I want to record the action performed on element and then repeat it.*

**How can I get it using C#?**

Btw. I use COMwrapper class for UIAutomation.

Comment: Do you mean, after you've got the focused window handle, spy it and rise and event when a button is clicked? In any case, you have to notice that there is no link between FocusChanged event and a button click or an input edited...

Answer (score 1):

After you get the element from the focus changed event, you can add handlers for button click (invoke), edited (property) and closed. Here's how:

```
private void OnFocusChange(object sender, AutomationFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var element = sender as AutomationElement;
    if (element == null) return;
    Automation.AddAutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler(element, Treecope.Element, OnChange, AutomationElement.NameProperty, ...);

    if (element.GetSupportedPatterns().Any(p => p.Equals(InvokePattern.Pattern)))
        Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(InvokePattern.InvokedEvent, element, TreeScope.Element, OnClicked);

    var window = element.Current.ControlType.Equals(ControlType.Window) ? element : GetElementWindow(element);
        Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(WindowPattern.WindowClosedEvent, window, TreeScope.Element, OnClosed);
}
```

Now, the qustion of which proprties to subscribe to, really depends on what events your element is sending. This you can view with spy tools like inspect, UISpy, UIAVerify, AccEvent, etc.